# mongodb: Trying to push a value in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, nosql

I'm trying to `$push` a value in an array inside mongodb. This is the query:

```
db.user.update(
{ "_id": 5ac34a3c23f1b0343c155782 },
{ $push: { "courseId":5acd192a3ff62a287452891f}});
```

The first id, after `_id` is coming from a user model with this parameter, `"_id" : ObjectId("5acb75a9e773ed2c10d5caa8")`.

The second id, after `courseId` is coming from this parameter `"_id" : ObjectId("5acd192a3ff62a287452891f")`.

Desired user model should look like:

> ```
> "_id" : ObjectId("5ac34a3c23f1b0343c155782"),
>         "tokens" : [ ],
>         "courseId" : [
>                 "5ac37f5cd494e905b86c2433",
>                 "<new id>"
>         ],
> ```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: shouldn't it be a string ? try wrapping the `id` with `"`  like : `$push: { "courseId":"5acd192a3ff62a287452891f"}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.user.update({ "_id": 5ac34a3c23f1b0343c155782 }, { $push: { "courseId":5acd192a3ff62a287452891f}})
```

You may need to use the `"_id": ObjectId("5ac34a3c23f1b0343c155782")` instead of just alphanumeric

Answer (score 0):

See if following snippet works for you:

```
        //following query will push to courseId 
        let modifier = {$push: { "courseId" :"5acd192a3ff62a287452891f"} };
        let options = {returnOriginal: false};
        db.collection('user').findOneAndUpdate({_id: ObjectId('5ac34a3c23f1b0343c155782')}, modifier, options)
        .then(function(op) {
             // see success or failure here in op
             console.log(op);
         })
```